# Draw a line connecting overhangs (ridges)

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I want to connect the overhang (ridge) points of an image to create a separation between left and right.

[image]
[image]

The final output should look like this. Then I can identify them as 4 separate inner contours.

[image: 4]

Is there a method to get the coordinates of the end points of overhangs (ridges) in order to draw a vertical line connecting them?
Or is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: It’s likely easier to solve your problem by changing how you got to this point.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Segment detector like [this one](https://github.com/primetang/pylsd)

you'll get the start & end. Then decide which segments to connect based on some 
criteria.

Note : (LSD is not supported since Opencv 4)

Comment: I'm using opencv 4. Therefore this solution is not possible

Comment: Check  the  link  . That's  not opencv  . It's  another  implementation.  pylsd .

Answer (score 0):

what you want is pretty customized which there might not be a common solution. And Im not sure you want to auto detect it or it is always a fixed pattern.

If it is a fixed pattern.

The first thing come to my mind is you auto crop 3 vertical section out. with each one like 10 pixel wide and 72 pixel tall.  Then detect HARRIS corner point. Then for each corner point detected. draw a line in bettween the corner point. At least, overlay this patch into the original image. dada you have it

Comment: What do you mean by auto crop? How can I get the exact location to crop?

Comment: Auto crop means for different images the vertical line is in different position and need to auto detect and crop. i assume you are dealing with a fixed pattern. so you can find those 3 ridge at exact same position for all images. when assume it is fixed position, then you just need to try the values. you can try from the horizontal position of 20. the first one should be around there.